# Can I update pycharm intellisense for python?

Tags: python, intellisense, pycharm

I want to know if it's possible to update Pycharm intellisense for python which doesn't care about capital or normal letters?
It's a pain in the neck to try both each time.
Currently I'm using pycharm 3.0 and python 2.7.4

An example of what I want:
For example I have a model named: 'MyModel'
I use to type first two letters and then ctrl+space to choose from the list. so if I type 'my' instead of 'My', the pycharm says: 'No suggestion'

Comment: [su] would be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: @BleedingFingers I doubt it would be a good idea to place it in Super User.

Comment: Can you describe your problem, your current description seems a little lacking,

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Question Updated with an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to set the **Case sensitive completion** to **None**.

In PyCharm 2016.3 this is in Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion.

[image]